# libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found

Tags: linux, ssh, x11, nvidia, opengl

I have some host named A and some computers named B. I try to run `glxgears` on host A via ssh:

```
ssh user@A -Y glxgears
```

and I get error:

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  43
  Current serial number in output stream:  42
```

Host A have an Intel graphics, and client B have an NVIDIA drivers:

**A**:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) UHD Graphics 600 (GLK 2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

**B**:

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: Quadro K2000/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 440.100
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 440.100
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 440.100
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Both A and B machines can run `glxgears` locally

I tried answers from these questions:

[libGL errors when starting X applications via SSH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486741/libgl-errors-when-starting-x-applications-via-ssh)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2363759

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/ssh-x-on-laptop-with-dedicated-graphics-card-produces-libgl-error/95155/3

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/ssh-x-on-laptop-with-dedicated-graphics-card-produces-libgl-error/95155/18

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=586777#c8

https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-steam-libgl-error-no-matching-fbconfigs-or-visuals-found-libgl-error-failed-to-load-driver-swrast/

But nothing helps